# How to fix problem with 555m Nvidia drivers not working on ASUS n55fs?

Tags: 12.10, nvidia

Downloaded the newest drivers from geforce.com (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-310.40.run).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to drop to tty1 and ran `sudo service lightdm stop`.

Created `/etc/modprobe.d/disable-nouveau.conf` to contain: `blacklist nouveau`

Edited `/etc/default/grub` so it contains `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"`

Ran `sudo update-initramfs -u` to update.

Rebooted.

Dropped back to tty1 again and stopped lightdm.

Ran `sudo modprobe -r nouveau`.

Ran `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-310.40.run`, the installer ran through no problems.

Ran `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, new config files were written.

Rebooted just to make sure.

When it reboots, resolution is 640x480. I log in, try to run `sudo nvidia-settings` and I'm told I am not using the Nvidia X driver.

`lsmod | grep 'nvidia'` outputs `nvidia 9402434 0` so its being loaded, I think.

EDIT:

When starting lightdm and logging in, I am presented with this error message.

```
Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors

none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:
Trying modes for CRTC 63
CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1920x1080@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 63: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1920x1080@60Hz (pass 1)
Trying modes for CRTC 64
CRTC 64: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1920x1080@60Hz (pass 0)
CRTC 64: trying mode 640x480@60Hz with output at 1920x1080@60Hz (pass 1)
```